# CSS Word-Spacing Group Words?

Tags: css, word-spacing

I am trying to place some URLS with a 10px word-spacing between them but I have no idea how I can group 2 or more words to act as a group and not have the word-spacing applying for them.

```
#spacing {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: middle;
    margin: 0 !important;
    word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

The Terms & Policies below got some huge space between them :)

```
<div id="spacing">
    <a href=""> Home </a>
    <a href=""> About </a>
    <a href=""> Terms &amp; Policies </a>
    <a href=""> Links </a>
    <a href=""> Advertise </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `margin` - `#spacing a{margin:0 10px}` instead of `word-spacing:10px` -> [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruN4/)

Comment: Worked awesomely! Thank you very much!